# xCode pass data between dynamically created ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to set up a project which dynamically creates ViewControllers based off a JSON file. I asked a question the other day about how to create this here

[xCode Dynamically create ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191056/xcode-dynamically-create-viewcontrollers)

So I have been able to create the ViewControllers dynamically and after playing around with it more, I have been quite easily set it up so when the app loads, it generates how ever many numbers of ViewControllers is specified in the JSON. I can also navigate between them easy enough and also have each screen set up buttons, views etc from the JSON. I do this simply by doing

```
NSDictionary *MainJSON = [sJson JSONValue];
NSArray *theArray = [MainJSON valueForKey:@"viewControllers"];
```

Then loop through theArray creating a ViewController instance.

My problem is, I want to be able to pass data between the ViewControllers. So say for example I set it up in the JSON so the first ViewController has a text field. The user will enter some data and I want to be able to set it up so when they navigate to the next screen, that data is carried to the next screen. I currently switch screens like this

```
-(void)nextScreen
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [vcArray count]; i++)
    {
        int iID = i+1;
        if([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] == iID)
        {
            ViewController *theVC = [vcArray objectAtIndex:i];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:theVC animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now usually each ViewController would have a class, so in the ViewController I am pushing I can do property and synthesise a NSString in that class, so when passing data to the next ViewController, I would just do this.

```
vc.theString = textField.text
```

But as I am dynamically generating these ViewControllers, I can't do this as I am only using one .h and .m file and each ViewController I generate is using the same XIB file. Does anyone have any ideas of how I could go about passing data in this set up?

Comment: Uhm...I don't understand, the fact that you have only one View Controller should make things easier. You can also store in your iOS app all the possible xib and instantiate view controller with a specific one, maybe adding a 'xib name' string property in JSON. Keep also in mind that UIView (label etc..) can also be recalled with tag number, you could store it to the JSON as well.

Comment: Yeah, been playing around with it for the past half an hour, and realised this can easily be achieved using the JSON. Basically I either use the tag method as you said, or I can give each label/textfield in each viewController an ID which I can use to connect them up. I have all the objects created stored in diff arrays, so can loop through them check which IDs match up and set the info up that way. Guess I shoulda played around with it a bit more before asking. Too early in the morning :P

Comment: If you stick your comment in as answer, I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that you need different xib for same view controller, you can supply all of them in the main iOS app, later by passing xib name in JSON you can instantiate that xib and assign to the controller.

If you also need to recall UIView objects you don't know by name, you can always use the tag attribute stored in JSON as well.
Maybe you can also store the UIView type, such as 'UILabel', 'UITextView', ecc... and call appropriate setter for value.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If I give each view a tag from the JSON, can easily connect up the objects I need.