# Creating ArrayList of activities dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to be able to dynamically create a list of activities, and store them in an ArrayList. I will also be giving each activity created a list of fragments which will be used to set up that activity. Is this possible on Android? I have done this on iPhone, basically I have a JSON file which sets up the number of tabs and screens in the app, see link below which shows how to set this up in iPhone.

[xCode Dynamically create ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191056/xcode-dynamically-create-viewcontrollers)

[xCode pass data between dynamically created ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222038/xcode-pass-data-between-dynamically-created-viewcontrollers)

I want to recreate something similar to this on Android. You see on the iPhone one, I have an arraylist, and I loop through the JSON and create a new instance of a ViewController class which I have set up.

On Android, I have an activity called DefaultActivity, I want to loop through and create several instances of this, so I can set up the number of tabs I need. I will then give each instance of the activity an arrayList of fragments which will be used to set up how each screen looks.

Is something like this possible on Android? Or how would I go about achieving something similar?

Thanks in advance:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a singleton with a collection of Activities.

On your DefaultActivity, exactly inside onCreate method, just add that instance to the collection on the singleton.

Then, all of your activities must extend DefaultActivity, so they will add themselves to the collection.

On the singleton side, define the methods you want to check activity count, or something like that.