# Dynamically create ViewControllers through JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to achieve this code [xCode Dynamically create ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191056/xcode-dynamically-create-viewcontrollers), but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

I need to dynamically create view controllers and then dynamically add buttons to those view controllers, then final make those buttons go to those view controllers when clicked.

First, I created a 'single view project' and then within the viewController.m file, I added the following code after (void)viewDidLoad.

```
/// DATA JSON ADDED TO NSMutableDictionary ...
NSMutableDictionary * allContent = [NSJSONSerialization
JSONObjectWithData:allContentData
options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
error:&error];
//// GO THROUGH DATA
if( error )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
//// CONTROLLERS
NSArray *xControllers = allContent[@"xControllers"];
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for ( NSDictionary *theConDetails in xControllers )
{
UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[viewControllers addObject:vc];
}
//// BUTTONS
NSArray *xButtons = allContent[@"xButtons"];
for ( NSDictionary *theButtonsDetails in xButtons )
{
NSString *xLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"Label"]];
xPositionX = [theButtonsDetails[@"PositionX"]intValue];
xPositionY = [theButtonsDetails[@"PositionY"]intValue];
xWidth = [theButtonsDetails[@"Width"]intValue];
xHeight = [theButtonsDetails[@"Height"]intValue];
xZorder = [theButtonsDetails[@"Z_Order"]intValue];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xcoPositionX, xcoPositionY, xcoWidth, xcoHeight);
[myButton setTitle:xcoLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(HOW DO i CONNECT THE BUTTON TO GO TO VIEW CONTROLLER:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view insertSubview:myButton atIndex:xcoZorder];
```

My JSON Data:

```
    {
xControllers: [
{
id: "1",
Name: "Screen 1",
Is_First: "Yes" <- MAKE THIS THE FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER
},
{
id: "2",
Name: "Screen 2",
Is_First: "No"
}
],
xButtons: [
{
id: "1",
Name: "Next",
Label: "Next",
View: "1", <- DISPLAY ON VIEW CONTROLLER
Link: "2", <- LINK TO VIEW CONTROLLER
PositionX: "0",
PositionY: "0",
Width: "100",
Height: "100",
Z_Order: "56",
},
{
id: "2",
Name: "Back",
Label: "Back",
View: "2",  <- DISPLAY ON VIEW CONTROLLER
Link: "1", <- LINK TO VIEW CONTROLLER
PositionX: "0",
PositionY: "0",
Width: "100",
Height: "100",
Z_Order: "56",
}
]
}
```

I help would be appreciated. I've been trying to work this out for over a week.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to set `Tag` property and use this property to get the corresponding controller form array:

```
...
...
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xcoPositionX, xcoPositionY, xcoWidth, xcoHeight);
[myButton setTitle:xcoLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTag:[theButtonsDetails[@"id"]intValue]];  // <---- See this line
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someButtonTouchEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
...
-(IBAction)someButtonTouchEvent:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllers[((UIButton*)sender).tag] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you NeverHopeless. It sounds like a great idea.

Comment: NeverHopeless im a newbie, sorry I'm getting this error regarding this IBAction code  viewControllers[((UIButton*)sender).tag - The error says 'Use of undeclared identifier 'viewController': did you mean 'UIViewControllers'?

Comment: Sorry I worked out the error. I did not declare the array in .h file.

Comment: However now the code breaks at [viewControllers addObject:vc]; }

Comment: What is the error ? Why do you initialize array with capacity 0 ? Try using `NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`  or `NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array]`and see what you get..

Comment: In my ViewController.m
`code`
etc...
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
etc...       
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[viewControllers addObject:vc];
etc...

-(IBAction)someButtonTouchEvent:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController pushViewController:*viewControllers[((UIButton*)sender).tag] animated:YES];
}
`code`

Comment: I'm getting an error with the above code now viewControllers[((UIButton*)sender).tag - The error says 'Use of undeclared identifier 'viewController': did you mean 'UIViewControllers'?

Comment: Hi NeverHopeless, it is possible for me to email you my code? .m file

Comment: Do you have to declare the array in .h file? like 
NSMutableArray *viewControllers; and then in .m file, what is the right one to use? like NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: The code breaks around [viewControllers addObject:vc]; I think when tries to loop again.

Comment: You should preferably use this: `NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];` Also what is the error that you get when the code breaks?

Comment: This is the code [link] http://pastebin.com/fyXNqDL9 [link]. I've tried to use NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array]; with no luck. The errors i seem to get is like this 'viewControllers __NSArrayM * @"1 object" 0x08d326c0'

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your code and i can read JSON File in side the View

```
for (NSDictionary *theButtonsDetails in xButtons ){

        NSString * xLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"Label"]];
        NSString * xPositionX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"PositionX"]];
        NSString *  xPositionY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"PositionY"]];
        NSString *  xWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"Width"]];
        NSString *  xHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theButtonsDetails[@"Height"]];

    UIButton * myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake([xPositionX doubleValue], [xPositionY doubleValue], [xWidth doubleValue], [xHeight doubleValue]);
    [myButton setTitle:xLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton.backgroundColor = [ UIColor grayColor];
    [myButton setTag:[theButtonsDetails[@"id"]intValue]];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview: myButton];
```

i replaced NSString instead of NSInteger.

[image]