# What is the Diffence B/W initwithnibname and init?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Whats the deference B/W using this :

```
   ViewController *vController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

and this :

```
ViewController *pController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Solved what?  What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initWithNibName` is use to initialize the view controller with its `XIB or NIB` where `init` is only initialize the class instance without any view.

Comment: i believe this is true answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess - as the method suggests, it should be pretty clear

initWithNib - loads controller with a xib/nib file
init - will not initialize attach any xib/nib file

Comment: Nitpick - `init` does initialize a view, just an empty one.

Comment: Is that like if i use **initWithNib** than i only use XIB controller and with **init** i can use dynamically created controllers also ??

Comment: Yes - you can dynamically manipulate the view with init. 
See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191056/xcode-dynamically-create-viewcontrollers